# Is there an API to get information on active US legislation?

Tags: web-services, api

I'm looking for an easy way to programatically find active legislation currently under review in the US Congress and Senate (date introduced, title, general subject, etc...). I've google'd a bit and haven't come up with anything. Does anybody know of an API that can access this data?

Comment: Have you looked at data.gov? You might find what you're looking for there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/congress_api

Comment: So you Googled "a bit" more and actually looked at the first result? :P

Comment: No, I saw your link (before you deleted it). You do the work for me and I give you virtual points.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at

- [Real Time Congress API from Sunlight Labs](http://services.sunlightlabs.com/docs/Real_Time_Congress_API/)
- [API from GovTrack.us](http://www.govtrack.us/developers/api) (beta as of this post)